# Date format dd/mm/yy

Tags: java, format

I got this problem in my code. I want to show a date in `dd/mm/yy`, for example `04/11/19`.I don't know how to do it, I tried something like this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy").format(getDate())
```

But it does `mm/dd/yyyy`. This is my code I tried to format:

```
for (Information t : list) {
    tblInfo.addItem(
       new Object[] { t.getName(), t.getLocation(), t.getTypeProduct().getDescription(), new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy").format(t.getTodayDate) }, null
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this 
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(getDate);